# how to change color of text for WinJS.UI.ToggleSwitch

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, winjs, toggleswitch

I am using a Toggle Switch in the settings pane. Problem is that the text in the title and labelOff, labelOn is not visible. I am not sure how can I change the front color or styles from the WinJS.UI.ToggleSwitch so that this text start displaying. Any examples will be highly appreciated.
Here is my html.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="mypage fragment"
            id="mysettings" 
            data-win-control="WinJS.UI.SettingsFlyout"  data-win-options="{width:'narrow'}">
            <div class="win-header">       
                    <button onclick="WinJS.UI.SettingsFlyout.show()" class="win-backbutton">
                    </button>
                <div class="win-label">My Settings</div>
            </div>
            <div class="mytoggle"  data-win-control="WinJS.UI.ToggleSwitch" data-win-options="{ title:'Test', labelOff: 'Close', labelOn:'Open', checked: true}"></div>
        </div>  
    </body>
</html>
```

Below is my css

> .fragment.mypage .mytoggle .win-title .win-labelOff{
>       color: green; }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can refer the css styling classes for [WinJS.UI.ToggleSwitch here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh701411.aspx).

default.js:

```
app.onsettings = function onsettings(e)
{
    e.detail.applicationcommands = {
        about: { title: 'About', href: '/pages/settings/about.html' },
    };
    WinJS.UI.SettingsFlyout.populateSettings(e);
}
```

/pages/about/about.css:

```
.myflyout .win-content .mytoggle .win-title
{
    color: blue;
}
```

/pages/about/about.html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link href="/pages/settings/about.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <!-- BEGINSETTINGFLYOUT -->
    <div class="myflyout" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.SettingsFlyout" 
       data-win-options="{settingsCommandId:'about'}">
        <div class="win-ui-light win-header" >
           <button type="button" onclick="WinJS.UI.SettingsFlyout.show()" 
            class="win-backbutton"></button>
           <div class="win-label">About</div>
           <img src="/images/smalllogo.png" style="position: absolute; right: 20px;"/>
        </div>                
        <div class="win-content">
            <div class="mytoggle" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.ToggleSwitch" 
               data-win-options="{title: 'example of toggle'}" >
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- ENDSETTINGSFLYOUT -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have updated my question with the code  I am using including your suggestion but I still don't see any text with toggle switch. Any thoughts what I am doing wrong

Comment: Try [this sample. scenario 5 html page](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/App-settings-sample-1f762f49/view/SourceCode#content). it has toggle switch control also.

Comment: updated answer. I could see toggle switch title in blue color for this code.

Comment: Thanks Sushil. I found out that it was <div class="mytoggle"  data-win-control="WinJS.UI.ToggleSwitch" data-win-options="{ title:'Test'}"></div> in my code causing problem. When I do this in two div as you have in code, it all works. I am not sure why it does not work within one div. Thanks again for your help though.

Answer (score 0):

As of 2016 I failed doing this with ".win-title". Instead used ".win-toggleswitch-header".